# Spring Data mongodb aggregation framework: ConditionalOperators in project() for median calculation

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, aggregation-framework

In a sample project with Spring Data 2.0 I'm trying to calculate the median temperature value of documents with the following format:

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("5ad28e92e284e00bbc0a9479"),
   "deviceId":"myId",
   "time":   ISODate("2018-04-21T23:28:18.632   Z"),
   "temperature":10,
   "_class":"com.github.paizo.monitorapi.model.Refrigerator"
}
```

From [here](https://www.compose.com/articles/mongo-metrics-finding-a-happy-median/) I grab an aggregation pipeline to calculate the median that I translated to the following Spring Data aggregation:

```
final Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
        match(
                Criteria.where(DEVICE_ID_FIELD).is(deviceId)
        ),
        group().count().as("count").push(sensorValueField).as("values"),
        unwind("values"),
        sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "values"),
        project("count", "values")
                .andExpression("(count) / 2").as("midpoint"),
        project("count", "values", "midpoint")
                .and(floor).as("low")
                .and(ceil).as("high"),
        group()
                .push("values").as("values")
                .avg("high").as("high")
                .avg("low").as("low"),
        project()
                .and(beginValue).as("beginValue")
                .and(endValue).as("endValue"),
        //FIXME if ODD => v1 == v2 then return v1 else v1 != v2 => return average(v1,v2)
        project().and(
                ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("beginValue").ne("endValue"))
                    .then("beginValue")
                    .otherwiseValueOf("(beginValue + endValue) / 2")
        )
);
```

A part for the possible errors in the calculation I was trying to made the final values checks in the last `project()`. **It does not matter what I write inside the `ConditionalOperators.when()` the resulting project will be empty** :

```
{  
   "aggregate":"refrigerator",
   "pipeline":[  
      {  
         "$match":{  
            "deviceId":"myId"
         }
      },
      {  
         "$group":{  
            "_id":null,
            "count":{  
               "$sum":1
            },
            "values":{  
               "$push":"$temperature"
            }
         }
      },
      {  
         "$unwind":"$values"
      },
      {  
         "$sort":{  
            "values":1
         }
      },
      {  
         "$project":{  
            "count":1,
            "values":1,
            "midpoint":{  
               "$divide":[  
                  "$count",
                  2
               ]
            }
         }
      },
      {  
         "$project":{  
            "count":1,
            "values":1,
            "midpoint":1,
            "low":{  
               "$floor":"$midpoint"
            },
            "high":{  
               "$ceil":"$midpoint"
            }
         }
      },
      {  
         "$group":{  
            "_id":null,
            "values":{  
               "$push":"$values"
            },
            "high":{  
               "$avg":"$high"
            },
            "low":{  
               "$avg":"$low"
            }
         }
      },
      {  
         "$project":{  
            "beginValue":{  
               "$arrayElemAt":[  
                  "$values",
                  "$low"
               ]
            },
            "endValue":{  
               "$arrayElemAt":[  
                  "$values",
                  "$high"
               ]
            }
         }
      },
      {  
         "$project":{  

         }
      }
   ],
   "cursor":{  
      "batchSize":2147483647
   }
}
```

That cause the error:

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: Command failed with error 40177: 'Invalid $project :: caused by :: specification must have at least one field' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Invalid $project :: caused by :: specification must have at least one field", "code" : 40177, "codeName" : "Location40177" }; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 40177: 'Invalid $project :: caused by :: specification must have at least one field' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Invalid $project :: caused by :: specification must have at least one field", "code" : 40177, "codeName" : "Location40177" }
```

I am doing something wrong with the last `project()`? Is it a Spring data issue?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question, maybe it can help others.

Turns out that the `$project` was not generated due to the missing `as()` after the `project.and(...)`;

The following example properly generate the `$project` for the conditional operator:

```
            project().and(ConditionalOperators.when(Criteria.where("beginValue").ne("endValue"))
                    .then("beginValue")
                    .otherwiseValueOf("(beginValue + endValue) / 2")).as("lowViewsQuestion")
```